# Bootstrap hidden-md not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to conceal column that col-md-0 in my screen on md size.
But It shows my screen . How can I hide that?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

is exist in my `<head>`tag

```
 <div class="container-fluid top-nav">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm col-md-1 left-fixed-bar">
                나왔다가 숨겨질 부분.
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 hidden-md left-fixed-bar">
                <i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>
            <!-- End of left part -->
            <div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm col-md-8 center-fixed-bar">
                나왔다가 숨겨질 부분.
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-9 hidden-md">
                숨겨져있다 나올 부분
            </div>
            <!-- End of center part -->
            <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-3 right-fixed-bar">
                <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>
            <!-- End of right part -->
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: just hide the div that you want to be hidden on mobile

Comment: Use the Bootstrap class col-sm-hidden instead of col-sm-0 an you are good.

Comment: I edit my codes, but not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there is no class such as `col-md-0` for your purpose you wll need to write a media query and set `width: 0%;` on the medium screen resolution. or you can use the `hidden-md` class for your requirement. Which will hide your div im medium resolution. I have attached the code spinet for you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
  </head>
  <body>
     <div class="container-fluid top-nav">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 left-fixed-bar">
                <i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm col-md-8 center-fixed-bar">
                EMPTY
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-9 hidden-md">
                TITLE
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-3 right-fixed-bar">
                <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: hidden-md class needs bootstrap javascript?

Comment: are you asking about bootstrap.js? if yes thats required. Bootstarp needs bootstrap.css, bootstrap.js and jQuery to work. hidden-md do not need any other javascripts to work other than these three.

Comment: You can test my code. That's working properly. If you copy paste this code and run in a local HTML file you can see that both the divs with content "EMPTY" and "TITLE" are visible on large screen. But on reducing the screen size ie on medium resolution screen, the second div will vanish. Its has 'hidden-md' class in it.

Comment: no, content "TITLE" should be invisible. It has class hidden-md.

Comment: on your screen , icons are invisible because of font-awesome CDN not exist

Comment: Yes on medium screen "TITLE" is invisible and on xs device "EMPTY" is invisible. That's what happening in my code also.

Comment: Umm.. I swear that yours not working on mine T. T I copy and paste perfectly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127262/discussion-between-nitheesh-and-).

Comment: I fixed It . Thank you .

Answer (score 1):

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid top-nav">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 left-fixed-bar">
                <i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm col-md-8 center-fixed-bar">
                EMPTY
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-9 hidden-md">
                TITLE
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-3 right-fixed-bar">
                <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: this is not working to me. I include `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">` in `<head>` tag

Comment: Try this  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

Comment: Try This  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

Comment: Don't Copy here the link is brokening so u can download the file from bootstrap tutorial